# Getting ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) while trying to setup kubernetes for the first time

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am totally new on Kubernetes, I am reading the book: Getting Started with Kubernetes from Jonathan Baier. After all the billing process from Google I was able to setup my project both in GCP and in my system, but then the book says that I need to execute:.

```
kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.sh
```

The first time, it reached the point from the following picture:

[image: First try]
I had to cancel it, because it took too much time. The second time it was able to pass that message, but then 3 error messages appears:

[image: Error Messages]

I saw in another post a similar issue, and someone said that gcloud needed a downgrade to version 167. But I am not sure if that also applies to this issue,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

well

All I had to do was open that link the error message gave me, then activate/enable the Compute Engine API, wait for some mins and then exute the kube-up script again..

Hope it can help someone later